# AngularJS - interactive table with Django

Tags: angularjs, django, html-table

I'm trying to create an interactive table, however, I'm not getting.
The first and second column comes from django and the other columns are inputs of type number, and the last column should do the math between (2º column - (3rd + 4rd + 5rd + 6rd + 7rd + 8rd column ))
I've tried everything and does not work, someone could help me?

The code below adds the columns, but not absolve the 2nd column, and enter a number in the input, it is copied to all of the same column.

```
<div ng-app="">
<table>
    <!--Field name of each column-->
    {% for i in prioridade %}
    <tr>
        {% for x in i %}
            <td>{{ x }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}

    <!--Table fill-->
    {% for w in table_01 %}
    <!--Ex: table_01: [['Fev/2015', 10000.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], ['Mar/2015', 911.9, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]-->
    <tr>
        <td>{{ w.0 }}</td>
        <td>{{ w.1 }}</td>
    {% verbatim %}
        <td><input type="number" ng-model="val1" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" ng-model="val2" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" ng-model="val3" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" ng-model="val4" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" ng-model="val5" /></td>
        <td><input type="number" ng-model="val6" /></td>
        <td>{{ w.1-(val1 + val2 + val3 + val4 + val5 + val6) }}</td>
    {% endverbatim %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <td>{% endverbatim %}{{ w.1}}{% verbatim %}{{-(val1 + val2 + val3 + val4 + val5 + val6) }}</td>
{% endverbatim %}
```

i think is something like this, becausew.1 is django template, should be out of verbatim

Comment: Thanks for the help, however, the last column is still not performing the subtraction, and enter a number in column 3 for example,  this number keeps appearing on all lines in column 3.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your entries are being duplicated between lines is becuase they are all referencing the same ng-model. e.g. All of the entries in column 3 are attached to the `val1` model. You have to either assign each item an individual model name, or use ng-repeat instead of django for loop to repeat your rows.

Perhaps this would give your desired result.

```
{% verbatim %}
    <td><input type="number" ng-model="{% endverbatim %}row_{{forloop.counter}}{% verbatim %}val1" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" ng-model="{% endverbatim %}row_{{forloop.counter}}{% verbatim %}val2" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" ng-model="{% endverbatim %}row_{{forloop.counter}}{% verbatim %}val3" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" ng-model="{% endverbatim %}row_{{forloop.counter}}{% verbatim %}val4" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" ng-model="{% endverbatim %}row_{{forloop.counter}}{% verbatim %}val5" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" ng-model="{% endverbatim %}row_{{forloop.counter}}{% verbatim %}val6" /></td>
    <td>{{ {% endverbatim %} w.1-(row_{{forloop.counter}}val1 + row_{{forloop.counter}}val2 + row_{{forloop.counter}}val3 + row_{{forloop.counter}}val4 + row_{{forloop.counter}}val5 + row_{{forloop.counter}}val6) {% verbatim %} }}</td>
{% endverbatim %}
```

I'm not sure how the mixing of verbatim and template tags will work, it's probably best to handle the calculation in your angular controller anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the help, now the inputs of the same column are no longer replicating the columns below, this is very good, however, in this last column showing the following: `{{ {% endverbatim %}w.1-(row-{{forloop.counter}}val1 + row-{{forloop.counter}}val2 + row-{{forloop.counter}}val3 + row-{{forloop.counter}}val4 + row-{{forloop.counter}}val5 + row-{{forloop.counter}}{% verbatim %}val6) }}`